# Does COS S3 support putBucketLifecycleConfiguration?

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

AWS S3 supports lifecycles for buckets, does this work in Bluemix S3?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#putBucketLifecycleConfiguration-property

When I call it (using the aws-sdk nodejs module), I get back a 400 saying 'The operation requested is not supported'. The docs say a subset of s3 is handled but I'm not sure what ISNT't handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, lifecycle configurations aren't supported at this time.  The full list of supported operations is on [the API overview page](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/about-compatibility-api).  If you want to, feel free to send me an email (nicholas.lange[at]ibm.com) and let me know what you are trying to do.  Having developer feedback makes it easier to advocate for prioritizing new feature work.

Also, FYI, there is a new release of object storage that will be available on the IBM Cloud platform (Bluemix) soon, with IAM permissions and OAuth2 support instead of AWS signatures.  The docs will migrate there shortly.